# Joining only specific rows

Tags: mysql, join

I am looking for an SQL query that will return a 1 or a zero depending on a joined row's content.

Two Tables:

Events:

- event_id
- descriptors

Qualifiers:

- qualifier_id
- event_id
- qualifier_type
- value

Each event can have multiple qualifiers.

The query that I currently have is:

```
select event_id, if(qualifier_type = 15, 1, 0)
from events 
join qualifiers q using (event_id)
where q.qualifier_type = 15;
```

In a perfect world, I would nicely normalize these tables and put the different qualifiers in with the events, but this isn't possible at the moment.

Edit: Currently, this query only returns rows that have the association. Instead, I need to return **all** rows and an extra column specifying if this association exists.

Comment: And what's wrong with your current query?  Are you looking for a list of events and an indication of whether qualifier type 15 is needed for that event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.event_id, COUNT(q.qualifier_type) AS needs_qualtype_15
  FROM events AS e
  LEFT JOIN qualifiers AS q ON q.event_id = e.event_id AND q.qualifier_type = 15
 GROUP BY e.event_id
```

This gives you a list of all events with an indication of whether the qualifier type 15 is associated with the event.

Another way of writing the same thing is:

```
SELECT e.event_id, COUNT(q.qualifier_type) AS needs_qualtype_15
  FROM events AS e
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT event_id, qualifier_type
          FROM qualifiers WHERE qualifier_type = 15
       ) AS q
    ON q.event_id = e.event_id
 GROUP BY e.event_id;
```

Both formulations rely on `COUNT(expr)` only counting non-null values.  For the events with a matching qualifier, the COUNT is 1; for the events without, it is 0.  The first version compresses the query by including the condition on qualifier type into the ON join condition.  The second version is clearer, but more verbose.  The chances are that a good optimizer will execute both queries the same way.

Comment: Instead, I need a list of **all** events - with an extra column specifying if a qualifier of type 15 is associated with the event.

Comment: @fluorescentLAMP: Both these should give you a list of **all** events because the events table is the dominant or preserved table in the left outer join.  There are no additional filters after the join, so all events will be preserved: where an event has a row in Qualifiers that has qualifier type 15, the COUNT(q.qualifier_type) will generate 1; where an event has no appropriate row in Qualifiers, the LOJ will generate an entry equivalent to `(event_id, NULL)` and the COUNT will generate 0.

Comment: Awesome. I missed the left join first time around. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Case
    When qualifier_type = 15 then 0
    Else 1
End
```

More here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: This still returns multiple rows for each event.

Comment: Since the question is tagged MySQL, maybe the MS SQL Server reference isn't the best source of information, though the CASE expression is Standard SQL and therefore is similar in most DBMS.

Comment: @fluorescentLAMP , use distinct for unique rows.  Depending on your tables structure though you still may get two rows (a 1 and a 0) for the same event id.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear what you're after, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   event_id, 
   CASE WHEN qualifier_type IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE 1 END AS [ColumnName]
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN qualifiers q 
WHERE q.qualifier_type = 15;
```